Prove whether $f_n(x) = \frac{nx^4+1}{nx+1}$ is uniformly convergent on $[1,c]$ and $[1,\infty )$
Could I please get some help on this uniform convergence question? I feel like my grasp on uniform convergence proofs is still a bit shakey.
The first question asks whether a sequence of functions $f_n$ converges uniformly on $[1,c]$ for each fixed $c>0 \in \mathbb R$. Apparently it does (or at least it's supposed to). In this case, I have the following proof:
On $x\in [1,c]$, $x>1\iff 1+nx > n+1$ and $x<c \iff x^3< c^3$ since $x^3$ is increasing on $[1,c]$, so $\frac1{nx+1}<\frac1{n+1}$.  Thus,
$$|f_n-f|_{\infty, [1,c]}=\left | \frac{x^3-1}{nx+1}\right |_{\infty, [1,r]}<\frac{|c^3-1|}{n+1}<\frac{|c^3-1|}{n}\to 0 $$ for each fixed $c>1$, so the convergence is uniform.
What's slightly tripping me up is the follow-up subquestion:

Does $f_n$ also converge uniformly on $[1,\infty)$?

I suspect that $f_n$ is not uniformly convergent on $[1,\infty)$. To prove this, I tried to find a particular $x_0\in [1,\infty)$ for which supremum norm of the difference doesn't converge to zero, i.e. $|f_n(x_0)-f(x_0)|_\infty \to L\ne 0$.
Since $[1,\infty)$ is unbounded from above, <<let $x=n$>>. The pointwise limit is $x^3$, so then $$|f_n-f|_\infty=\left| \frac{n^3-1}{n(n)+1}\right|_{\infty, [1,\infty)}=\frac{n^3-1}{n^2+1}\to \infty,$$ so the convergence is non-uniform.
Is this 'proof' valid, or have I performed an erroneous step somewhere? In particular, I'm not sure whether I'm allowed to pick $x=n$ since $x_n=n$ isn't Cauchy in $\mathbb R$.
Essentially, I tried using the contrapositive of this result:

Theorem. Suppose $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$, $f_n$ are all continuous, and $x_n\to x$ with $x\in [a,b]$. Then $\lim\limits_{n\to
> \infty}f_n(x_n)=f(x)$.


Does $\sup_{x \in [1, \infty)} |f(x) - f_n(x)| \to 0$?

Ok I think I get what you mean here, but does it not suffice to simply bound the norm of the difference from above by some constant sequence $M_n$ that is independent of $x$?

What you’re doing with evaluating at $x=n$, is bounding the sup norm from below by a sequence which tends to infinity. Which definitely suffices.

@LeeFisher apologies if this is a stupid question, but how does that bound the supremum norm from below?

$\sup_{x \in [1,\infty)} |f(x) - f_n(x)| \geq |f(n) - f_n(n)|$

I don't understand your notation, but your 'proof' is essentially correct.
Let me rewrite it more properly:
The sequence $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[1,\infty)$ if
$$
\sup_{x \in [1,\infty)} |f_n(x)-f(x)| \to 0 \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty.
$$
But
$$
\sup_{x \in [1,\infty)} |f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq |f_n(n)-f(n)| = \frac{n^3-1}{n^2+1} \to \infty \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty;
$$
hence, $f_n$ does not converges uniformly to $f$ on $[1,\infty)$.
